# How do I downgrade a jailbroken iPhone 4 on iOS 7.0.3 to iOS 6.X.X?

Tags: iphone, ios, downgrade

I know about other similair questions on AD, but they are from quite a while ago. Things can change quickly.

I do know about this method: http://www.syncios.com/blog/how-to-downgrade-ios-7-to-ios-6-1-3-on-iphone-4-using-ifaith/

But iFaith can't find any SHSH blobs for my phone.

I have not saved any SHSH Blob's because got the phone and jailbroken it two days ago.

So here's the september 2014 question:

I'm on a jailbroken iPhone 4 iOS 7.0.2, can I downgrade to iOS 6.X.X? If yes how?